# Installing mono on open suse

Tags: opensuse, rpm, mono

I'm trying to install mono on my open suse linux.

I downloaded the latest rpm packages from the mono [page](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.2.3/linux/x64/)

and tried to install the mono-core package with the --test attribute

```
rpm -ivh --test /home/martin/Downloads/mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64.rpm
```

but got an error saying:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        mono(System.ComponentModel.Composition) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
        mono(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
        mono(System.Data) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
        mono(System.Runtime.Serialization) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
        mono(System.ServiceModel) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
```

I understand that these dependencies should be installed first, but there isn't any just 'mono' package. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I deleted my comments, to remove cluster (and erroneous info) from this QA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mono documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Installation) is not very clear on exactly how to install the packages they provide: `install the packages "mono" ...` while there is no single package with that name.

One of the multitude of packages you have to download probably provides `mono` as a virtual package, providing the dependency your installation attempt complains about. Installing all packages at once should solve the issue:

```
cd /home/martin/Downloads
rpm -ivh *.rpm
```